# How do I do the "Hook and Throw" maneuver?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations, achievements

How do I do the "Hook and Throw" move in *Assassin's Creed Revelations*? I don't recall it from the tutorial. I need to do some for the Mercenary challenge Set 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're sprinting, with the hookblade equipped, tap <kbd>B</kbd> (or <kbd>O</kbd> for PS3) right as you approach your target. If you HOLD the button, you'll only do a hook and run, which isn't what you want. It takes a little practice to get the timing right, but it's pretty fun when you do it right. Side note: It doesn't seem to work on Janissaries. They always manage to avoid the "throw" part.

Comment: I think this move can also be done during combat. I am almost certain that's how I pulled them off and completed the challenge, because I barely ever did the hook moves while running.

Comment: Yeah, you can do this in combat if you're using the Hidden Blade.

Comment: @Shinrai are the controls for the maneuver the same when you're locked into combat? Since RT is for defending and not for sprinting? Or do you have to break out of locked battle mode (whatever it's called) to do the trick?

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller I could have sworn you could do it out of a grab, but maybe I was remembering incorrectly because now that I think about it I don't recall ever doing it.  (I hardly ever grab people except to throw them off ledges, anyway).  Perhaps you have to unlock your target, yeah.  I'll play around when I get a chance.

Comment: @Shinrai I'll play with it tonight and we'll report back. There is a RT+B counter-grab move when locked on that ends up with Ezio throwing the enemy on the ground. Maybe that's what we're thinking of?

Comment: I only managed to pull it off in combat.

Answer (score 2):

It's done in the same fashion as the Hook and Run move, only instead of **holding** your button, you need to **tap** it instead. I did the Hook and Throw a number of times during the tutorial on accident because I wasn't holding my button long enough to do the Run.